# Django QuerySet retuns empty queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have not been able to tell why this model query returns an empty queryset...

Here are my models:

```
class Marks(models.Model):
    klass = models.ForeignKey(Klass,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    stream = models.ForeignKey(Stream,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    mark = models.IntegerField()

class Klass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

The view.

```
def ResultsView(request):
    query = request.GET.get('klass')
    if query:
        queryset = (Q(klass__name__icontains=query))
        the_student = Marks.objects.filter(queryset).distinct()
        all_results = {'the_student':the_student,'query':query}
    else:
        all_results =  {}
        
    return render(request,'exams.html',all_results )
```

The form template

```
    <form action="{% url 'search_marks' %}" method="GET">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input class="" style="flex:50%" type="text" name="klass">
         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"></button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The url

```
path('search_m',ResultsView,name='search_marks'),
```

I try getting the results here

```
{% for mark in the_student %}
    {{ mark }}
{% endfor %}
```

When I print the_student from the view it gives `<QuerySet []>`

When I try `queryset = (Q(mark__icontains=query))` brings an answer for the mark.
I only want a result for klass

Comment: what is problem now?

Comment: @NEBEZ, I need a non-empty queryset for this     queryset = (Q(klass__name__icontains=query))

Comment: if you print this request.GET.get('klass'), what do you get? Have  you included the {% csrf_token %} tag?

Comment: did django show any error or just you can not see results?

Comment: Also problem here is you should using klass.name in view because it is forigen key.

Comment: @Abdullah csrf_token no need when method is ```GET```

Comment: @Abdullah, print(query) gives the selected item from the dropdown, meaning the issue is in the queryset

Comment: Did you solved?

Comment: No, I was not successful at all. @NEBEZ

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the whole queryset in your template.

Try

```
{% for mark in the_student %}
    {{ mark.klass }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: the_student is not an issue here, it was just a typo,

Answer (score 0):

the_Student is your response key but you use the_student.

the_student != the_Student

you just change the

```
{% for mark in the_student %}
  {{ mark.klass }}
{% endfor %}
```

to

```
{% for mark in the_Student %}
  {{ mark.klass }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: the_student is not an issue here, it was just a typo,

Comment: I thoroughly tested your code. Line by line. There was no problem. Did you put the data in the database?

Comment: @Maleki. Yes, it's in the database.